# List all containers in an Azure blob client - ListContainers method missing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to obtain a list of all containers within an Azure Storage blob client using `WindowsAzure.Storage` v8.5.0.

MSDN doesn't offer documentation for v8.5.0 - its latest is v8.4.0, but even if I downgrade to this version I still have the same problem: [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listcontainers?view=azurestorage-8.4.0#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobClient_ListContainers_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_ContainerListingDetails_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) that there's a `ListContainers` method, but intellisense in Visual Studio says there isn't, and I get a build error if I insist on trying to call such a method.

I've checked and the version of the assembly in the \bin directory *is* v8.5.0 (and v8.4.0, when I try that)

I've used .NET Reflector to look inside the packages and can find no such method.

So what has happened to `ListContainers`, and if it's been removed then how else can I list all containers?

Comment: Are you using this library in a .net core project?

Comment: Yes. Is the method not exposed to such projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Core version of Storage Client library does not support synchronous methods as of today. There's an open ticket on Github for that: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367.

To list containers, you will need to use Async methods. Please use [`ListContainersSegmentedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listcontainerssegmentedasync?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) method for this purpose.